# reduce combines an array into a single value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I was reading an [article here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter6.html#p3a26d72d5d539372)

> `reduce` combines an array into a single value by repeatedly using a function that combines an element of the array with a base value. This is exactly what sum did, so it can be made shorter by using reduce... except that addition is an operator and not a function in JavaScript, so we first had to put it into a function.

```
function reduce(combine, base, array) {
  forEach(array, function (element) {
    base = combine(base, element);
  });
  return base;
}

function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function sum(numbers) {
  return reduce(add, 0, numbers);
}

function countZeroes(array) {
  function counter(total, element) {
    return total + (element === 0 ? 1 : 0);
  }
  return reduce(counter, 0, array);
}
```

- `reduce` combines an array into a single value? : does it mean all the elements are getting sum-med or concatinated?
- combines an element of the array with a base value? : combines all elements or an element?
- What is that author trying to explain? Can someone clarify the concept?

Comment: please add the function `forEach`. and then i suggest to use it with an array of numbers or string to get a result.

Comment: It's just basic English. *repeatedly using a function that combines an element of the array with a base value*. So yes, since I "repeatedly combine an element", after all the repetitions are done I have combined all the elements, just like saying "repeatedly scratch my head" means scratching my head many times. * combines an array into a single value? : does it mean all the element?* What else could it possibly mean? Reduce is remarkably simple, and in addition to the MDN page there are hundreds or thousands of blog posts which explain it if this one doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reduce operation works by iterating over the array and presenting an *accumulator* to a custom callback. That callback is free to do with that accumulator whatever it wants. Typically the accumulator is, for example, a number that the callback *adds* to. So an array of numbers will be *reduced* to one number.

`Array.prototype.reduce` is really just an abstraction over this:

```
var acc = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    acc += arr[i];
}
```

Expressed as reduction:

```
var acc = arr.reduce(function (acc, n) {
    return acc + n;
});
```

Obviously, you don't have to use `+`, you can do anything else, like:

```
var acc = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    acc.push(arr[i]);
}

var acc = arr.reduce(function (acc, n) {
    acc.push(n);
    return acc;
}, []);
```

The result is the original array, nothing has been "reduced". (Yes, this is pointless, but demonstrates the freedom you have.)

The accumulator is simply the value that that callback returned during the previous iteration. A reduction operation proceeds as:

- callback takes empty accumulator* and first value of array, returns value
- callback takes return value of previous iteration and second value of array, returns value
- [repeat for each element in array]
- `reduce` spits out result of last callback as result of reduce operation

<sub>* See API documentation for details on first iteration behaviour.</sub>

Comment: well, not the original array, a shallow copy.. and you can create local variables inside the function even in ES5 for more complicated processing, handle sparse arrays and over time your brain will twist in a way that you will start to think that one day you will understand functional programming languages!

Comment: _Yes, this is pointless, but demonstrates the freedom you have._ This isn't pointless. It demonstrates that you can deduce `map` from `reduce`

Comment: A wonderful explanation, and many thanks for taking the time to write it. I wish I could bring myself to write answers like this, but I just figure since there's like a million books and articles out there explaining it, why bother?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer I want to point out that `reduce` is a very **generic concept**. It is even more generic than `map` or `filter`, since you can deduce them from `reduce`.

You can reduce not only primitives like `Number`s, but almost everything. As an illustration I give you an example for the reduction of functions:

```
const inc = x => x + 1;
const sqr = x => x * x;
let fs = [inc, sqr];

fs.reduce((f, g) => g(f), 2); // 9
```

This is just function composition. Hence we can utilize reduce to compose functions.

Comment: Yes, a good classic example for reduce. However, if the OP cannot parse simple phrases like "repeatedly using a function that combines an element of the array with a base value" then I doubt if he's going to grok function composition.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce reduces the list over a function. It is too cheap to say that it combines it into a single value, as you can reduce it to a list.

Reduce is also known as the fold construction infunctional programming languages. If you do a bit of research on fold ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function) ) and then try to come back, it might give more sense.

Comment: A list is a single value.